# Bookmarking common places in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, file-management

The Lightroom catalog shows my entire collection, as a tree of directories.  If I move from one project to another, I have to navigate the tree.  Then, I have to navigate back.

Can I set some kind of *favorite* or *bookmark* to currently-common places I'm working?

To be clear, I want to return to a particular **directory** containing one event or shoot, and these will change.  For example, I have a family-business product shot and a Saturday picnic, filed in different directory trees so they are in rather deep directories and different from each other.  I want to move between them as a recently-used-directory.  But next week I won't care about the picnic anymore, but will have a different directory next to it (since that's filed under ⋯\Days\2016\April\26-picnic and next one will also be based on the date.  But ⋯\Clients\balm\1016\bottles, on the same server, is a pretty deep set of directories to go up and down and they'll never normally appear next to each other.

Comment: Can you create smart collections with similar names that show everything in each folder?

Comment: You mean define a "smart collection" to just show everything in one specific directory (not really smart), but name them with a convention so they all cluster together in one place like `favorite-work` and `favorite-fun`?

Comment: Yes exactly that. You could do it as a manual collection, but the advantage of the Smart collection should be that it can 'watch' the folder and identify if virtual copies have been created. If you created them as manual collections and were working in there, I can't remember whether Lightroom would know to put the virtual copy into the collection based on the fact that the original is in that collection

Comment: @laurencemadill: It does, at least in Lightroom 5. If you, hover working in a Smart-Collection which is based on some other standard collection, and create a Virtual Copy in that Smart collection, then the Virtual Copy exists only in the folder, and not in one of the collections - A behavior which annoys me a lot...

Comment: What is "hover working"?

Answer (score 1):

I hope it could be helpful for you:

1. Create manual collection "__bookmarks"
2. Put in this collection just a single representative photo of every few folders you work on actually.
3. Everytime you need to move to the folder of your choice:

   a) go to "__bookmarks"

   b) right click a photo of your interest

   c) choose "Go to folder in library"

Additionally you can create collection SET "__bookmarks" and put there collection "__bookmarks" - just to be this collection always at hand of "Collections" panel (on top of it).

Additionally, if you don't use "Target Collection" function you can use it for bookmarks.

1. Right click on "__bookmarks" and choose "Set as Target Collection"
2. When you want to add representative photo to bookmarks - select it and press "B"
3. When you want to remove a photo from bookmarks - select the photo and press "B" again

Comment: Nice idea "go to folder in library"; I'll look into it.  For the second, I'm already using *target collection* for posting on web albums.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to explore using the various flagging, keywording, and filtering options more. Based on comments, I would suggest you find a way to identify "favorite" -- whether marked with five stars, a pick, a color, a "favorite" keyword, etc. Then, also tag your photos with the "fun" and "work" keyword.

Now, you can simply filter by both "favorite" and "fun" to find those photos. Easier still, create a Smart Collection with those two keywords and now it's always one click away.

Comment: I don't want to tag every photo.  Just return to the "folder" (directory) I was using on the other project.  I don't want every photo I ever worked on to appear either, as that defeats the purpose: the bookmark would be moved from time to time.

Comment: Uh, you realize how fast and easy it is to add and remove a tag, both from a single photo and from many? Temporary tags are a great way to help in reorganization. Don't want to see everything -- just figure out a filter to apply, perhaps date-focused. Step away from the old idea of folders and folder structure and you'll find that the metadata options are far more capable and flexible.